# NHibernate query over baseclass not initialize derived class properties

Tags: nhibernate

Consider following class structure.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
    public IList<AnimalProperty> AnimalProperties { get; set; }
    public IList<OtherAnimalProperty> OtherAnimalProperties { get; set; }
}

public class Dog: Animal
{
    public DogProperty DogProperties { get; set; }
}
```

With following mapping for the Dog class

```
HasOne(x => x.DogProperties).ForeignKey("Id");
```

I now have following query to retrieve a list of objects of type Animal.

```
list = session.QueryOver<Animal>()
       .WhereRestrictionOn(e => e.SomeData).IsIn(someList.ToArray())
       .Fetch(e => e.AnimalProperties).Default
       .Fetch(e => e.OtherAnimalProperties).Default
       .List();
```

My list now contains an object of type Dog (as expected), but the DogProperties property is `null`. Meaning, the one-to-one class defined in the mapping is not initialized.
However, NHibernate generated a nice joined query that retrieves also the DogProperty data from the database. It just does not create the class through this query.

```
SELECT this_.Id as Id0_1_, this_.Name as Name0_1_, this_.DogName as DogName0_1_,
       this_.AnimalType as AnimalType0_1_, dogpropert2_.Id as Id1_0_, 
       dogpropert2_.MyProperty as MyProperty1_0_ 
FROM [Animal] this_ left outer join [DogProperties] dogpropert2_ 
       on this_.Id=dogpropert2_.Id
```

Can anyone elaborate what I'm missing here? Or is this a bug/default behavior of NHibernate QueryOver?